# Dropbox install fails in 12.04 TLS (32 bit)

Tags: installation, dropbox

In Ubuntu I choose the "Try Ubuntu" mode.

Every time I try to install DB via download from the DB-Site and Software Center it confirms as "intalled". But the Dropbox is nowhere to be found. It is not in the list of intalled programs...

Would appreciate any ideas. Hope to get the hang of linux as an OS soon!

Answer (score 1):

Try run it from terminal using the command:

`dropbox`

Download and install it from here https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx if something wrong occur it's probably because you are using Ubuntu via CD

Don't forget to choose the 32 bit version for Ubuntu, it's the first option. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It workes that way! Will check linux basics next week. :)

Comment: @Marcell please check my answer as the correct if you think like that. Thanks. :)